# Optimise Jolt Transform (if/else)

Tags: java, apache-nifi, jolt

Given the following transform I want to always output **`occupyAddressYn`** which would allow for me to remove the **`"true"`** branch

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "occupyAddress": {
        "occupyAddressYn": {
          "false": {
            "$": "occupyPremises.indicator",
            "@(2,nameOfOwner)": "nameOfOwner",
            "@(2,ownerConsentToOccupyYn)": "registeredOfficeConsentIndicator"
          },
          "true": {
            "$": "occupyPremises.indicator"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the **input** JSON value is

```json
{
  "occupyAddress": {
    "occupyAddressYn": "false",
    "nameOfOwner": "Brian Wilson",
    "ownerConsentToOccupyYn": "false"
  }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to remove the **`"true"`** but always write the **`occupyAddressYn`** (currently the **`'$'`**) value in **`occupyPremises.indicator`**?

any pointers greatly appreciated.
RonM.

Comment: Can you please express the problem by adding the Input, and expected output( and preferably the current input as well )?

Comment: It's more of always outputting "occupyPremises.indicator" as seen from the above I have to duplicate "$": "occupyPremises.indicator" for both. what I'd like to do is simplify the transform to something like..

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "occupyAddress": {
        "SOMETHING HERE?": "indicator",
        "occupyAddressYn": {
          "false": {
            "@(2,nameOfOwner)": "registeredOfficeOwner",
            "@(2,ownerConsentToOccupyYn)": "registeredOfficeConsentIndicator"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: apologies for the formatting

Comment: input json
{
  "occupyAddress": {
    "occupyAddressYn": "false",
    "nameOfOwner": "Brian Wilson",
    "ownerConsentToOccupyYn": "false"
  }
}

Comment: I think the answer is 
 "occupyAddress": {
          "occupyAddressYn": {
            "@(0)": "occupyPremises.indicator",
            "false": {
              "@(2,nameOfOwner)": "registeredOfficeOwner",
              "@(2,ownerConsentToOccupyYn)": "registeredOfficeConsentIndicator"
            }
          }
        }

Comment: Can you please edit the question with the expected outputs when `occupyAddressYn` is `true` and `false` ...

Answer (score 0):

You require 2 operations to achieve a if else in your case. You can use this Jolt Spec for generating the required output :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "occupyAddress": {
        "occupyAddressYn": {
          "false": {
            "$": "occupyPremises.indicator",
            "@(2,nameOfOwner)": "occupyPremises.registeredOfficeOwner",
            "@(2,ownerConsentToOccupyYn)": "occupyPremises.registeredOfficeConsentIndicator"
          },
          "true": {
            "$": "occupyPremises.indicator",
            "@(2,nameOfOwner)": "Truncate",
            "@(2,ownerConsentToOccupyYn)": "Truncate"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
,
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "Truncate": ""
    }
  }
]
```